# bash, watch command with kubecolor

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I use kubectl with watch so I can have a "realtime" view of what I'm ding as I'm updating pods and stuff, usually I go like:

```
watch -n1 kubectl get pods
```

Now I want to do the same using kubecolor as the output is much better but the watch command won't display the colors, as I read on the man pages I'm trying:

```
watch -n1 --color "kubecolor get pods"
```

Without any luck, colors are not being displayed :(

Does someone knows how to properly do it ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Have you tried `kubecolor --force-colors ...` ?

Comment: @Philippe this also worked! thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `kubecolor` detects that it is running non-interactively.
Therefore the problem is not the `watch` command, but `kubecolor` itself that disables color output when combined with watch.

As commented by Philippe the switch `--force-colors` for the `kubecolor` command prevents this.

In general: If you are using a linux operating system, you can use `unbuffer` to get the output working as expected. For Debian/Ubuntu install the `expect` package to get `unbuffer`.

The command to be used could then look as this:

```
watch -c unbuffer kubecolor get pods
```

In addition to that `kubectl` (and `kubecolor`) support the `--watch` switch itself. Does not solve all use cases, but since it uses the API server watch method it is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the core issue, I wasn't aware of that, I'm running Ubuntu and just installed the expect package so I can have access to the unbuffer command. It worked perfectly

Comment: On macOS with homebrew, you can install unbuffer by `brew install expect`. Then you should be able to run e.g. `watch -c unbuffer kubecolor get pods`.